# programming code in tex

Tags: code

After adding a piece of code in text, I wish it could look like this:
[image: shell code in text].

Now I used `\verb@@` to insert command, but it does not handle line break and indentation.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  What have you done so far? Could you please add some working code?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Usually program developers use markdown to write document, but I would like to use tex to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution for your black box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=black,colback=black,coltext=white]
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
$ svn log --xml | grep P \textcolor{yellow}{"^<author"} | sort u | \textbackslash
  perl -pe \textcolor{yellow}{'s/<author>(.*?)<\textbackslash/author>/$1 = /'} > users.txt
        \end{Verbatim}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, the solution is very inspiring.